# msi installation failure (Error 1001. InstallUtilLib.dll: Unknown error. DEBUG: Error 2769: )

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

Eariler, We had our solution built with visual studio 2010 and we had .vdproj file for creating the build and it was working fine perfectly.(setup is installed and works as expected).

But recently, we have upgraded our solution to visual 2017. We did the migration successfully but for build or setup .vdproj was not working fine as we were not able to open .vdproj in visual studio 2017. So, I just googled around & found out the following solutions:

1. Install visual studio installer plugin in 2017
2. User InstalledShield Limited editions

We have gone with first option. We just installed that plugin. Post this, We are able to open that existed visual studio 2010 .vdproj in visual studio 2017. It got migrated without any error. We had custom actions(primary output) in the project, we just re-added them. *.vdproject gets complied successfully and generates .msi file

But while installing it by command line or explicit(double click the .msi). We get following error:

```
Error 1001. Error 1001. InstallUtilLib.dll: Unknown error.
DEBUG: Error 2769:  Custom Action _71938623_DFF8_4B88_8552_77D8706A0C48.install did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2769. 
The arguments are: _71938623_DFF8_4B88_8552_77D8706A0C48.install, 1, 
CustomAction _71938623_DFF8_4B88_8552_77D8706A0C48.install returned actual error code 1603 
(note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

After googling a bit about this, We found couple of suggestion such as adding or removing slash in arguments using command line installation.

But even though we are doing explicit installation(by double clicking the setup file) still we get the above mentioned error.

In case, We remove the custom action from project installation, then msi gets installed successfully. So, we don't know what is the problem with those custom actions.

We tried of debugging custom action by using Debugger.Launch(). But installer doesn't reach that portion. Prior to that we get above mentioned exception.

Don't know what to do.

We are scratching our head. Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Could it be because of .net framework installed. we have installed .NET 4.6.1 too.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: _Custom Action ... did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs._. So you have to review the code of the custom action and check that it has a matching `MsiCloseHandle()` call for each `MSIHANDLE` it opens.

Comment: It's a crash, most likely in your managed code custom action. InstallUtilLib.dll is a shim C++ Dll that calls into your code using reflection, that's why you see it mentioned.

Comment: I stuck with the same problem for cli/c++app. C# app is working fine. did you find any solution?

Comment: @SaRaVaNaNDM In my case, I deleted and re added the custom action option and fix my problem. I hope it works for you too!!!

Comment: Still not working. Are you using cli/c++?

Comment: No I did not use CLI\C++ it was plain c# project. But in my opinion should not be about type of projects. It is depdent on depdencies

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this InstallUtilLib.dll: Unknown error when trying to install an .MSI built with the Visual Studio Setup & Deployment project types:

I recently had this error after migrating a Visual Studio Setup & Deployment project to a new machine and new version of Visual Studio (where the installed .NET frameworks were likely different).  In my case, removing my .NET custom action from the Setup project got rid of the error, but my code was not the root cause.  The root cause was forgetting to check the Launch Conditions (View->Launch Conditions) of the Setup Project, where I needed to change the .NET Framework Launch Condition to match what was actually installed on the machine I migrated to (and not what was on the old development PC).  Also, you'll need to change the prerequisites by right clicking on your Setup & Deployment project and clicking Properties.  Then click the Prerequisites button and make sure the .NET Framework prerequisite matches what version your application targets and what version you used for the Launch Condition.